# If the scope of an Azure Policy with DeployIfNotExist effect is resource group, will it be able to deploy resources?

Tags: azure, scope, azure-policy

[DeployIfNotExists policy at Subscription level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998680/deployifnotexists-policy-at-subscription-level/66153339#66153339)

In this Question's Answer, it was mentioned "Azure Policy is capable of deploying resources at the Subscription level". Does this mean Azure Policy can deploy resources only when the scope is a subscription/management? If the scope is a resource group then deployment won't work?

Answer (score 1):

DeployIfNotExist effect can deploy at Subscription and at RG scope. You define it in **deploymentScope** attribute. RG is a default one. Details can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deployifnotexists